# AWS SES in laravel showing error while execute on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, curl

Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Is the above error occur because of HTTP in the localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the email is not registered in AWS SES which I have been used.